# ¿Qué formato deberían tener los nombres de tecnologías/lenguajes?

Tags: discusión, formato

En SOes los nombres propios de tecnologías o lenguajes de programación se pueden encontrar de múltiples maneras, por ejemplo:

- [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
- Python
- **Python**
- *Python*
- `Python`

Yo normalmente uso el primero o el segundo, pero he visto que mucha gente utiliza el último. ¿Hay alguna norma de estilo sobre cuál debería usarse?

Comment: no me gusta cuando se edita una pregunta para cambiar un nombre propio por su etiqueta, queda feo, la letra es chiquita y agrega un vinculo innecesario, ademas suele estar debajo de la pregunta.

Comment: @rnrneverdies sí. Ese tipo de ediciones deberían rechazarse al no mejorar el texto en nada. Y últimamente he visto bastantes de esas

Comment: ¿Debería haber una *única* norma de estilo sobre esto?

Comment: @dwarandae Esa es una buena pregunta. En mi opinión, seguir un formato consistente en el sitio sería ideal, aunque siendo realista no siempre es posible, y por tanto algún tipo de _norma_ sería buena. Con ello no quiero decir que sea única y que todo el mundo deba seguirla, cada cual escribe como quiere dentro de lo entendible y adecuado, pero por ejemplo a la hora de hacer ediciones sería bueno que hubiera consistencia (aunque no creo que se debiera editar una pregunta sólo para hacer cambios de este tipo, sí se podrían aplicar si hubiera otros cambios a hacer)

Comment: La pregunta en parte viene porque he visto bastantes ediciones en las que lo único que se hace es poner los nombres de tecnologías como `código` sin aportar ninguna mejora adicional (dejando errores ortográficos o texto innecesario)

Comment: Creo que alguien (tal vez @JuanM o @Konamiman) debería crear una pregunta con respuestas a temas específicos para casos como este y dejar claro cuál debería ser el formato que se debe usar. Por mi parte considero que se debe poner el lenguaje/tecnología respetando el nombre original: "Python" a secas, sin formateo y respetando la mayúscula, "python" es incorrecto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo utilizo Python (o tecnología X) a secas.

---

Uso de **``` `` ```**: El sombrear o tratar de resaltar palabras con **`` ` ``** no me parece adecuado, puesto ese símbolo se debe utilizar para *resaltar código* que está puesto directamente en una frase u oración en el párrafo. Es más, puedes utilizar el acceso directo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> y ver los resultados por ti mismo.

Ejemplos:

Ejemplo 1: `Código resaltado` dentro de la oración. Al presionar la combinación el texto se enmarca por los caracteres **`` ` ``**.

Ejemplo 2: Código resaltado en párrafo. Al presionar la combinación le agrega 4 espacios automáticamente.

```python
def codigo_resaltado
end
```

Negrita: Solo por algún caso particular, podría ponerlo en negrita enmarcando la tecnología con doble asterisco **`**`**, ****como en este caso****, o doble guión bajo **`__`**, **__como en este otro caso__**. Si es que realmente necesita resaltarse. Este me parece que es más a gusto personal, y yo no lo uso.

Cursiva: Mismo caso anterior, solo que la diferencia es que en vez de doble asterisco o guión bajo, es un solo asterisco, **`*`**, o un solo guión bajo, **`_`**.

Utilizar etiquetas *(tags)*: Las etiquetas creo que son más para colocarlos en la parte de etiquetas debajo del contenido de la pregunta. Si tu pregunta necesita más etiquetas, quizás debas revisar tu problema puntual y reducir el alcance de tu pregunta. Claro, un proyecto mediano o grande usa todo un grupo de tecnologías, pero dudo que tu pregunta en particular para este sitio requiera que uses todas ellas para replicar el caso. Leer [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para más detalles.

Comment: Definitivamente de acuerdo con esto. Los nombres de tecnologías no necesitan ser formateados como código

Answer (score 2):

Yo normalmente uso **negritas** en las palabras clave, creo que se resalta bastante bien, no creo que sea correcto resaltarlas como código.

Answer (score 0):

Mi manera actual de formatear las publicaciones es la siguiente.

Aunque aquí solo se pregunta por los nombres de los lenguajes, intentaré dar una respuesta un poco más abierta.

Letra normal -> Para la mayoría del texto.

*Letra cursiva* -> Para tecnicismos en inglés. En esto se incluyen:

- Los nombres de los lenguajes, que los pongo en mayúsculas, ejemplos, PHP, Python, C#.
- Palabras como mouse, keyboard.

`Monoespaciado` -> Para código fuente, nombres de variables.

**Negrita** -> Para rutas de archivos, puntos centrales de la publicación, palabras propias del problema.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Hay alguna norma de estilo sobre cuál debería usarse?

Luego de 1 año y 10 meses **no existe una norma particular para SOes** acerca del estilo a usar para dar formato a los nombres de lenguajes/tecnologías

Lo anterior porque las respuestas previas han sido publicaciones en las que el autor comparte lo él hace.

En SO he encontrado poco sobre el tema:

La etiqueta [writing-style](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) a la fecha sólo tiene seis preguntas. De estas, me parece que sólo una habla sobre aspectos "cosméticos"

- [Is it worth having guidelines for highly colloquial and comedic writing styles?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327295/1595451). La [respuesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327302/1595451) con mayor puntuación, 57 al momento, indica que no se requiere una política de este tipo.

Claro que lo anterior es allá y no necesariamente tenemos que adoptar eso, sin embargo, lo que asumo como la conclusión a la fecha es que el tema de guía de estilo **no es de un tema interés general en SOes**.

Comment: Encontré [Standard way to format names of applications/technologies/etc.?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266239/1983854) que habla precisamente de esto. Aun con pocas visitas, la respuesta aceptada y con más votos habla de lo que mencionaba la aceptada aquí. A saber, que usar [tag] es liante y usar `tag` también, por el hecho de que el código se debería usar únicamente para código. Cursivas, negritas, etc ya dependerían de gustos de cada uno (o de la RAE).

Comment: @fedorqui : Buen hallazgo, gracias por compartirlo.

Answer (score -2):

Yo personalmente uso el último,

- `Python`

¿Por qué? Porque el primero parece que sale torcido y distrae al leer, me refiero que a aun estando en la misma línea éste es desplazado un poco hacia abajo [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), parce o cambia el estilo de letra y el tamaño, en en mi opinión.

También lo uso esa manera estilo para recalcar tecnologías y otras cosa, porque creo que hace mas fácil de leer y entender lo que se quiere trasmitir en la pregunta.

Básicamente uso el último para dar algo de `estilo al texto`, pues si además es muy largo y habla de varias `tecnologias` se hace mas cómodo de leer he intento separar los bloques de texto.

Aunque esto con un punto y seguido igual iría mejor que con un punto y aparte, creo que hace más cómodo su lectura además que de alguna manera se incita a leer al `encontrarce` con una pregunta muy extensa, y si tienes que volver a leer algo encontrar más rápido en qué párrafo se encuentra lo que buscas.

P.D: Y el tag [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) fuera del meta aún me parece más incómodo que el del meta, pero solo es mi opinión.

Comment: Yo tenía entendido que ese estilo era para código y sólo código, por eso me choca verlo en nombres propios

Comment: la verdad es que realmete nunca he leido nada sobre que su uso sea solo para codigo, pero puede que tenga razon, pero me imagino que de existir alguna norma seria creada en SO original, seria cuestion de que @JuanM , lo mirase y si procede crear una encuesta, o algo asi para ver si puede usar algun tipo de resaltado para las tecnologias y si es asi se podria llegar a un consenso de cual seria la mas adecuada. Saludos

Comment: No existe norma en sí, pero encontré esta [discusión sobre el tema en el meta de SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) donde casi de manera unánime se desalienta el uso de bloques de código para resaltar algo que no sea código, nombres de ficheros o URLs.

Comment: 1- Parte comentario largo) gracias por la info, pero para ser sincero cuando dijo de forma unanime y sabiendo la cantidad de usuarios con las que consta SO me imagina mas votos en los comentario apoyando lo que dice, casi que me parecio gracioso cundo los vi, (pero no se lo tome a mal), por otro lado siempre se dice o se quiere hacer creer que SO en español tendra sus normas ect. y siempre si se propone algo o se actua diferente al site original siempre dicen que tal o cual cosa esta mal y te redireccionan a un post o argumento de SO que lo trata,

Comment: 2- Parte comentario largo) al final parece que se crea una ilusion falsa de independencia, pero no digo que no se pueda aprovechar los años de experiencia que tiene SO y aplicarlos aqui, solo opino que se tiene que tener algo de digamos decicion para decir, y porque no se puede hacer asi o de esta manera, no se si me explico. Es que eso de de solo para codigo pues que quieres que le diga, realmete es un subrayador, pero como cada uno es diferente y lo respeto, yo veo una pregunta sin estilo y es como si ver el windows 1.0 comparandolo con un esccritorio actual.

Comment: 3- Parte comentario largo)  Solo decirle que gracias por abrir el tema y que pese a lo que yo crea tambien respeto cualquier forma en la que se edite el texto, por ultimo he visto mucho mas el subrayado 4 que el 1, pero eso no quiere decir que tenga que ser el estandar, pero igual indica lo que a la comunidad le gusta mas. Saludos

Comment: 4- Parte comentario largo) P.D: Tener en cuenta que el usuario nuevo y diria que hasta no tiene porque ser nuevo, es muy probable que nunca vea este hilo, porque la gran mayoria no entran en el meta y aun haciendo una encuesta que tenga ciertos votos a favor o encontra de uno u otro estilo no indica lo que la comunidad preferiria, es mas en este meta en español casi que el 99% de los que entran dirian que son usuario de SO e igual ven lo que esta fuera de las formas de actuar en SO y lo tachan de que no se puede o que no es correcto. Saludos

Comment: Tiene razón en que la comunidad es nueva y acabará dictando sus propias normas, pero creo que deberíamos tener en cuenta las normas y estilos de SO y otros sitios de SE. Muchos vienen de fallos/problemas que tuvieron en el pasado y que nosotros acabaremos cometiendo también si los ignoramos, cuando evitarlos ahora sería mucho más sencillo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en un parte dije ...pero no digo que no se pueda aprovechar los años de experiencia que tiene SO y aplicarlos aqui... por lo que estoy a favor de usar esa experiencia como tu bien añades para evitar fallos/pro, pero tambien creo que el estilo es una cosa que la comunidad puede ir aplicando como mejor se crea, lo importante creo es que el texto tenga formato y coherencia, que no de la sensacion que se tiro el texto sin mas como pregunta, que tenga algo de estructura ect. porque yo he visto pregunta que estan todas en el mismo parrafo siendo esta muy grandes y no dan ganas de leer

Comment: @AngelAngel No se porque el -1, en mi caso yo también uso este formato, creo que esta decisión debería radicar en el administrador principal, y nosotros como "administradores" aplicar esta regla.

Comment: @Elenasys yo deje un comentario en este hilo diciendo algo sobre una encuesta, si, lo que buscaban era crear un standard, y tambien expongo el porque y de mas cosas, que no es que use ese formato porque si, lo uso porque creo que tiene muchas ventajas, y los -1 seran de usuarios que no les gusta, todo es respetable, pero no dicen el porque no les gusta solo que es para codigo, y yo pregunto, por que solo es para codigo, cuando es un subrayador, y lo que sucede muchas veces te remiten a un post en ingles, a lo que añado esa es la forma de crear un SO en español que sea independiente. Saludos