# Cuando arreglo una pregunta que en especifico tengo que hacer

Tags: discusión, formato

Tengo el caso de que las personas nuevas cuando hacen una pegunta ponen algo así.

ejemplo :

Estoy usando javascript para hacer una function y cambiar un texto que dice "hola mundo"

tengo que cambiarlo así

Estoy usando **javascript** para hacer una `function` y cambiar un texto que dice `"hola mundo"`

cual es la mejor manera o como se tiene que hacer bien, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 4):

## Respuesta corta

Si el motivo principal de editar una pregunta ha sido distinto al aplicar estilos a palabras clave como corregir las etiquetas, el título, aplicar formato a un bloque de código, lo mejor sería considerar el caso particular de cada lenguaje ya que algunos cuentan con comunidades con ciertas prácticas de estilo y formato muy arraigadas mientras que en las comunidades de otros lenguajes podrían no ser las mismas o incluso no haberlas.

## Explicación

El ejemplo que proporcionas parece ser el caso de una mala pregunta. En esos casos es mejor no editarla y dejar un comentario de que no es una buena pregunta para SOes que falta mostrar el esfuerzo que ha realizado así como lo buscado en el propio sitio he investigado. En estos casos es útil dejar el enlace a **Cómo escribir una buena pregunta** para lo cual puedes escribir `[ask]` lo cual será mostrado como un enlace al artículo de ayuda correspondiente.

Si el ejemplo sólo es para ilustrar la aplicación de estilos, negritas para el nombre de lenguajes, el formato de código en línea para términos en inglés y el resultado de código en preguntas de una línea, **no lo hagas**, es una edición que generalmente aporta poco o nada, ya que generalmente no ayudan a hacer la pregunta más clara y sólo provocará que la pregunta se suba en la lista de preguntas por actividad, la cual es la vista predeterminada.

De [Editar preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

> **No os animamos a hacer ediciones minúsculas o triviales**: intenta mejorar la publicación considerablemente cuando la edites, corrigiendo todos los problemas que encuentres.

Por otro lado, y como mencioné en la parte superior, si el motivo principal de editar una pregunta ha sido otro como corregir las etiquetas, el título, aplicar formato a un bloque de código, el aplicar estilos debe ser con la finalidad de facilitar la lectura. Lo mejor sería considerar el caso particular de cada lenguaje ya que algunos cuentan con comunidades con ciertas prácticas de estilo y formato muy arraigadas mientras que en las comunidades de otros lenguajes podrían no ser las mismas o incluso no haberlas.

Nótese que tenemos una pregunta sobre aplicación de estilos publicada en los primeros meses de SOes la ha tenido una participación relativamente baja y pocas visitas, al día de apenas 191.

Preguntas relacionadas

- [¿Qué formato deberían tener los nombres de tecnologías/lenguajes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/448/65)
- [kbd debe ser usado solo para formato de teclas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/489/65)
- [¿Qué deberíamos hacer a las preguntas del tipo: no he intentado pero quiero respuesta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/840/65)
- [¿Qué hacemos con el incremento de preguntas que piden código sin haber intentado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2840/65)

Comment: no me entendiste me refiero a cuando acomodas una pregunta como tratar las palabras claves y los códigos entre otros detalles para mejorar la pregunta esos solo es un ejemplo de una pregunta nada mas